# PHP breadcrumbs, display all but current folder/page

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I have some code on my php page which generates a bread crumb structure such as:

history >> Gallery >> thumbs

When I am viewing the contents of my the thumbs folder on my php page, I want to display all the breadcrumbs except for the current folder I am in, so my ideal breadcrumb structure if I am in my thumbs folder on my page would be:

history >> Gallery

This seems likes a pretty simple problem, and I have tried the following code but I still have the same problem where the folder I am viewing on my PHP page displays in my breadcrumbs

```
$output = array();
$chunks = explode('/', $breadcrumbs);

for($i = 0; $i < (count($chunks) - 1); $i++)
{
$output[] = sprintf('<a href="index.php?folder=%1$s">%1$s</a>', $chunks[$i]);
}

echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);
```

Any ideas? Would it be simpler to change the breadcrumb variable I am passing and remove the current folder from it?

the breadcrumb variable that is passed looks like this: history/Gallery/thumbs/

Comment: How about count($chunks) - 2

Comment: Just remove the last item from the array with [array_pop()](http://us2.php.net/array_pop) before your loop.

Comment: http://papermashup.com/how-to-display-breadcrumbs-on-your-site-using-php/

Comment: Both of these are good suggestions, my brain just isn't working this morning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $output = array();
    $breadcrumbs = "history/Gallery/thumbs/";
    $chunks = explode('/', $breadcrumbs);

    for($i = 0; $i < (count($chunks) - 2); $i++){ //-2 since we dont want the last element
        $output[] = sprintf('<a href="index.php?folder=%1$s">%1$s</a>', $chunks[$i]);
    }

    echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);
?>
```

We change `count($chunks) - 1` to `count($chunks) - 2` since we don't want the last element

Comment: Right, this is pretty much what I used to fix my problem.